# How do I replace the second occurrence of a whitespace in each line with 'sed' or 'awk'?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file `hashes` which has many lines that look like this:

```
wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmbKi6XiMmf4YfvKXhqVPymD1HDwJ3WqukjyLuEvnrZrCz The_Supremes_-_My_World_Is_Empty_Without_You_(lyrics).mkv
```

All the lines in `hashes` will follow the pattern:

```
wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/hashthatis46characterlong nameOfAfileWithoutSpaces
```

as they are written by my script with the following lines of code:

```
find ~/pCloudDrive/VisualArts/Films/Fiction_Movies -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +200M -exec ipfs add --nocopy {} \;>>~/CS/ipfs/hashes && \
sed -i 's;added ;wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/;g' ~/CS/ipfs/hashes
```

All hashes are going to be 46-character long and they typically [start with 'Qm' but this may not necessarily be
the case in the future.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6861/what-datatype-should-i-use-for-an-ipfs-address-hash)

I want to replace the second space of each line of this file with ' -O ' so that it looks like:

```
wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/hashthatis46characterlong -O nameOfAfileWithoutSpaces
```

I tried `sed 's/[0-9A-z]{46,46}\s/& -O /g' hashes` but to no avail - I get the following output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: Invalid range end
```

How do I do this? Would `awk` present a better solution for this problem than `sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as this

```sh
sed 's/ / -O /2' input
```

where the trailing `2` in the sed command means "the second occurrence".

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk and `gensub()` to change the second occurrence on each record:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/ /," -O ","2")}' file
```

For example:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5  | awk '{print gensub(/ /," -O ","2")}'
1 2 -O 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have `nameOfAfileWithoutSpaces` it is possible to get desired result another way using GNU `sed`, namely:

```
s/\([^[:space:]]*\)$/-O \1/
```

this does capture non-whitespace characters which are followed by end of line (`$`) then does replace by `-O`  followed by these characters. I tested in using [sed.js.org](https://sed.js.org/) and for input

```
wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/hashthatis46characterlong nameOfAfileWithoutSpaces
wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/hashthatis46characterlong anotherName
```

output is

```
wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/hashthatis46characterlong -O nameOfAfileWithoutSpaces
wget https://ipfs.io/ipfs/hashthatis46characterlong -O anotherName
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`:

```
$ awk '{$3="-O" OFS $3}1' file
```